# style a group of eight elements with nth-of-type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to style a group of divs so that every eight elements get the same left positioning. So not the every eigths element, but a group of eight elements.
I've tried this with css / jquery but it only styles every eighth element, which is wrong.

```
var cells = $('.board-cells'),
        cellUnit = 70,
        startPos = -35;

    var left;
    for(j=0; j<8; j++){
      left = startPos+(cellUnit*j+1) + 'px';
    }
    for(i=0; i<cells.length; i+=8){
      var cellItem = $('.board-cells:nth-of-type('+i+'n+0)');
      cellItem.css('left', left);
    }
```

Comment: Curious what you are trying to do. Are all the divs the same width?  Can you show your HTML markup?  There might be a pure CSS way to do this...

Comment: I'm trying to create a game board layout.. I got the right top positions for my divs, but I'm struggling with the left position for the groups of 8 .. I'd like -34px
36px
106px
176px
246px
316px
386px
456px to be the left positions of every group of 8 divs

Comment: I also posted an only CSS answer. J's does seem like overkill in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your issue:

```
var cellUnit = 70;
var startPos = -35;

$('.board-cells').each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).css('left', startPos + cellUnit * (i % 8) + 1 + 'px');
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ku1gnokb/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: this gives the left position 525
1085
1645
2205
2765
3325
3885
4445 to every 8th div unfortunately

Comment: How did you want the result to be? @xxx12123

Comment: What left positions do you expect?

Comment: I'd like to get the left positions -34px
36px
106px
176px
246px
316px
386px
456px for each div groups of eight

Comment: Ok I got it. I edited my answer and added a demo link. Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make a grid you could maybe create an outer div with a fixed width and then each tile within can have a fixed width that is about 1/7 the width of the outer div and have float: left styling.

If you do your math right then every 8th div should automatically break to the next row.

Read up on floating divs (and clearing floats!) Here https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ for the full meal deal

Answer (score 1):

How about this, no script, just CSS.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;  
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .img {
  height: 70px;
  width: calc(100% / 8);
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+1):after {
  content: '1';
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+2):after {
  content: '2';
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+3):after {
  content: '3';
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+4):after {
  content: '4';
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+5):after {
  content: '5';
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+6):after {
  content: '6';
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+7):after {
  content: '7';
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+8):after {
  content: '8';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

      <div class="img"></div><div class="img"></div>
      <div class="img"></div><div class="img"></div>
      <div class="img"></div><div class="img"></div>
      <div class="img"></div><div class="img"></div>
      
      <div class="img"></div><div class="img"></div>
      <div class="img"></div><div class="img"></div>
      <div class="img"></div><div class="img"></div>
      <div class="img"></div><div class="img"></div>

    </div>
```

---

With this CSS you can target each group with left value

```
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+1) {
  left: -34px;
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+2) {
  left: 36px;
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+3) {
  left: 106px;
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+4) {
  left: 176px;
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+5) {
  left: 246px;
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+6) {
  left: 316px;
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+7) {
  left: 386px;
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(8n+8) {
  left: 456px; 
}
```